# Dynamically created method? _one_time_conditions_valid_718?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I'm new to RoR and jumping into a big RoR project. I used railroady to create a diagram of all of the models and controllers. I've noticed that many of the controllers begin with as many as five methods in the form

```
_one_time_conditions_valid_XXX?
```

where XXX ranges from 200 to 1116. However, these methods don't appear in the actual code. Are these methods automagically generated by some gem? I can't find a reference to this for anywhere.

Comment: Seems these are `ActiveSupport` callback methods at least as far as `AbstractContoller::Base` is concerned. I will have to keep digging to find where they are defined if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so here is your [Reference](https://github.com/carlhuda/rails-bundler-test/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb). These methods are defined in `ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback` in a method called `#_compile_per_key_options`  Line 159. It looks like this

```
  def _compile_per_key_options
    key_options = _compile_options(@per_key)

    @klass.class_eval <<-RUBY_EVAL, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
      def _one_time_conditions_valid_#{@callback_id}?
        true if #{key_options}
      end
    RUBY_EVAL
  end
```

It is then used for supplying data to the `before`, `after` and `around` filters through 2 different methods called `#start` and `#end`.

Both `#start` and `#end` check for these methods like so

```
return if key && !object.send("_one_time_conditions_valid_#{@callback_id}?")
```

From what it looks like the whole purpose of these methods is simply to determine if a callback as been defined and then if so compile the appropriate hooks.

These hooks are about as clear as their names. `before` hooks run before the defined action and access the data before the action gets it, `after` hooks run after the defined action and access the data after the action gets it, and `around` hooks wrap an action and triggers the event they `yield`. You can even define your own such as:

```
class Record
  include ActiveSupport::Callbacks
  define_callbacks :magic
  def magic 
    run_callbacks :magic do 
      puts "Abracadabra"
    end
  end
end
class Magician < Record
  set_callback :magic, :before, :perform
  def perform
     puts "The Magician will now perform a Trick"
  end
  set_callback :magic, :after do |object|
     puts "Tada"
  end
end
```

This is clearly shown by

```
magician = Magician.new
magician.magic
#Output:
#  The Magician will now perform a Trick #(before callback)
#  Abracadabra #(actual event)
#  Tada #(after callback)
```

This means if your controllers have "as many as five" of these that there are an equal amount of filters in the form of something like `before_filter`, `after_filter`, `before_action`, `around_action`, etc. (the list of available callbacks is pretty long)