# Is there any way in Ruby/Rails to add a pre/post execution hook on all method calls within a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example lets say I have the following code

```
def my_method
   do_work_1
   5.times do
     puts "This is a test"
   end
   do_work_2 "Hello"
   do_work_3 do 
     puts "Inside block"
     do_something_else
   end
end
```

What I would like is to have the following logs:

```
do_work_1 called with no params
do_work_1 finished
do_work_2 called with param "Hello"
do_work_2 finished
do_work_3 called with a block param
do_work_3 finished
```

I could create a helper method and do something like the following

```
def my_method
   log_call method(:do_work_1)
   5.times do
     puts "This is a test"
   end
   log_call method(:do_work_2) "Hello"
   log_call method(:do_work_3) do 
     puts "Inside block"
     do_something_else
   end
end

def log_call(m, params)
   puts("#{m.name} called with params #{params}")
   m.call(params)
   puts("#{m.name} finished")
end
```

But this isn't very pretty and would require us to use `log_call` on every method we call that we want logging. Is there a better way to go about achieving this goal?

Comment: There's so many ways this can be implemented, although if you literally mean you only want them logged if they're called within `my_method` the options are fewer. It can be as simple as delegating, or something along the lines of https://medium.com/rubyinside/how-i-built-timeasure-part-1-motivation-method-wrapping-1304cf841206 which IIRC is largely `Module#prepend` https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Module.html

Comment: (The reason why it's wonkier if you only want the aspects during a call to `my_method` is that either (a) the work to instrument/deinstrument needs to be done in `my_method` or as an aspect of `my_method`, or (b) you need the call stack in the methods in question)

Comment: Ya unfortunately what I need is only to log these calls when invoked from within `my_method`. I'll take a read of that article and see if that gives me what I need!

Comment: There's also... Forwardable? from core Ruby.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49563339/in-ruby-whats-the-best-way-to-execute-a-block-around-a-child-method or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615065/dynamically-created-method-one-time-conditions-valid-718 came to mind when I saw this question maybe you can gather some insight from those as well

Comment: You can use [ActiveSupport::Callbacks](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks.html) if you want something similar to the callbacks used in models/controllers.

Answer (score 0):

In production code, I would use something explicit, similar to the `log_call` solution you already have. I would probably use something even more basic. Yes, it's a lot of typing, but everyone on your team will understand it.

In non-production code, or as a temporary measure, we can consider `Module.prepend`.

```rb
require 'minitest/autorun'

class Worker
  def do_work_1(*); end
  def do_work_3(*); end

  def my_method
    do_work_1
    2.times { puts "This is a test" }
    do_work_3 { puts "Inside block" }
  end
end

module WorkLogging
  %i[do_work_1 do_work_3].each do |m|
    define_method(m) do |*args, **kwargs, &block|
      puts format('%s called with: %s', m, [args, kwargs, block&.source_location].compact)
      super(*args, **kwargs, &block)
      puts format('%s finished', m)
    end
  end
end
Worker.prepend(WorkLogging)

class MyTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_1
    expected = <<~EOS
      do_work_1 called with: [[], {}]
      do_work_1 finished
      This is a test
      This is a test
      do_work_3 called with: [[], {}, [\"derp.rb\", 10]]
      do_work_3 finished
    EOS
    assert_output(expected) { Worker.new.my_method }
  end
end
```

The question has been simplified trivially in the interest of brevity. Exact output format is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I'm curious what makes the one solution production safe and the other not?

Comment: @NewToBlue This is just my opinion, but I put value on simpler, more explicit solutions that I'm sure my team will understand. The combination of `Module.prepend` and `define_method` that I've shown would not be understood by junior engineers. It's not a matter of production _safety_ per se, but a matter of team _comprehension_.